# prototype = object.create()

Tags: javascript, объекты, прототипное-наследование

Совершенно не понимаю, что значит такая запись:

```
(function DatatypeBird() {}
 function Bird() {} 
DatatypeBird.prototype = Object.create(Bird.prototype);)
```

Я знаком с прототипами, понимаю, как это работает, когда в прототип класса заносят функцию, что делает `object.create` тоже понимаю, но вот смысла вот этой второй строчки и как она работает не понимаю. Объясните, пожалуйста, на пальцах, зачем оно нужно и как работает.

Comment: это один из вариантов реализации наследования: функции которые были в прототипе `Bird` будут скопированы в прототип `DatatypeBird`

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался